# In the novelization of Poltergeist, the Beast had a name. Anyone know what it was?

Tags: poltergeist

Back when the movie came out, I read the novel right after seeing the movie. The Beast had a name, I remember Tangina making fun of the name. It was "G'something" and the description was her making a coughing sound with it. If someone can dig that up, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to answer. I was watching an episode of Angel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was **gHala**.

> *"**So, Beast,**" she gloated. "**Now I can say your name. gHala.** gHala. A
> paltry name, not even so base. It surprises me not, that you would not
> say it. It must be an embarrassment to you. gHala." She said it as if
> she were clearing her throat.*
>
> <sup><sub>[Poltergeist - A Novel](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/407225.Poltergeist)</sub></sup>